# Can a ViewModel class in Android contain a constructor?

Tags: java, android, android-viewmodel

I was going through the [Paging Libary Overview](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging?hl=en&authuser=1) and found this:

[image]

I'm a little confused as to how a constructor has been created in the ConcertViewModel class. I've read that earlier, it was the library ViewModelProviders that was in-charge of actually creating the ViewModel. And this library, by default, expects the ViewModel class to have no constructors.

Now, I know that ViewModelProviders has been deprecated and we now use ViewModelProvider directly. But I was under the impression that it was still forbidden to create a constructor in our ViewModel class. Am I missing something here?

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create viewmodel by using ViewModelProvider like a factory method. Constructor can be also used to pass custom parameters required by the viewmodel.
This also helps when you implement any dependency injection in the viewmodel.